# On a Flot chart show grid even when axis are disabled

Tags: charts, flot

I have a flot chart that covers an image and I needed to disable x-axis and y-axis in order to cover the chart the whole image, which works fine. However, I want the grid to visible which disables with the axis automatically.

```
grid:{    
      verticalLines:true,
      horizontalLines:true,
}
```

has not worked out.

Answer (score 0):

So far, I could only find a solution via markings:

```
grid:{          
      markingsColor:"rgba(100,100,100,0.5)",
      markingsLineWidth:1,
      markings: [
        {xaxis: {from:272,to:272},   yaxis:yoffset},
        {xaxis: {from:544,to:544},   yaxis:yoffset},
        {xaxis: {from:816,to:816},   yaxis:yoffset},
        {xaxis: {from:1088,to:1088}, yaxis:yoffset},
        {xaxis: {from:1360,to:1360}, yaxis:yoffset},
        {xaxis: {from:1632,to:1632}, yaxis:yoffset},
        {xaxis: {from:1904,to:1904}, yaxis:yoffset},
        {xaxis: {from:2176,to:2176}, yaxis:yoffset},
        {xaxis: {from:2448,to:2448}, yaxis:yoffset},
        {xaxis: {from:2720,to:2720}, yaxis:yoffset},
        {xaxis: {from:2992,to:2992}, yaxis:yoffset},
        {xaxis: {from:3264,to:3264}, yaxis:yoffset},
        {yaxis: {from:120, to:120}},
        {yaxis: {from:392, to:392}},
        {yaxis: {from:664, to:664}},
        {yaxis: {from:936, to:936}},
        {yaxis: {from:1208, to:1208}},
        {yaxis: {from:1480, to:1480}},
        {yaxis: {from:1752, to:1752}},
        {yaxis: {from:2024, to:2024}},
        {yaxis: {from:2296, to:2296}},
        {yaxis: {from:2568, to:2568}},
      ],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show a grid but you don't want label axis to be shown use this trick:

```
yaxis: 
{
    show: true,
    font: {size: 0 }
},
```

and do the same for `xaxis`.

```
xaxis: 
{
    show: true,
    font: {size: 0 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i was able to achieve this using

`yaxis: { min: -1160, max: -120, ticks: [ ],`

leaving the tick points in the `[ ]` blank.

the min/max numbers are irrelevant, just an example. I'm also using version `0.83`